# Triangle Inequality Proof

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

I need to prove that

$$|n^3 − 2000| \le  n^3 + 2000,$$

for $n$ a natural number.

I understand that I need to use a form of the **triangle inequality**, but I cannot figure out how to do so.

I know that there is a form of the Triangle Inequality where 
 $$|x+y| \le |x|+|y|$$  but I'm getting confused on how to decide what $x$ and $y$ are in terms of $n$.

Comment: This should hold for $n^3<2000$. What about for $n^3>2000$?

Comment: Often, the best way to prove that $|x| \leq M$ is to prove $-M \leq x \leq M$.

Answer (score 2):

$n$ cannot be negative so that $|n^3|=n^3$ and obviously, $|-2000|=2000$. Thus,
$$\begin{align}|n^3-2000|&=|n^3+(-2000)|\quad\text{then use Triangle Inequality to get}\\
&\leq |n^3|+|-2000|\\
&=n^3+2000\end{align}$$

Comment: So by stating this, we have successfully proved the statement?

Comment: Yes, of course. It follows from the fact that if $x,y\in\Bbb R$ then $$|x-y|\leq |x|+|y|.$$

Comment: This proves it, but only since $n$ is natural meaning that $n>0$ so that $\vert n\vert=n$ and we can say $\vert n^3\vert=\vert n\vert^3=n^3$. Otherwise, the inequality is false for some negative $n$.

Comment: This makes sense now! I understand that a natural number cannot be negative, and I can see now how it follows from the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at a more general situation: For $x,y > 0, |x-y| \le x+y$. Start out with $0 \le 4xy \implies -2xy \le 2xy\implies x^2+y^2-2xy \le x^2+y^2 + 2xy\implies (x-y)^2 \le (x+y)^2\implies \sqrt{(x-y)^2} \le \sqrt{(x+y)^2}\implies |x-y| \le |x+y|=x+y$ which is the claim.